# VB.NET: Building an Event Manager - Listeners

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, listener

I'm in the research stage of a project that will require the development of a custom event manager for computer game events.

In the past, the *routing* code for polling the correct pieces of code for event consumption  has been placed entirely within the Event Manager's *ProcessEvents()* function. Example: The UI needs to be provided the opportunity to consume a Mouse-Click Event, but a player object does not.

The size of the upcoming project is pretty big, and I can see it becoming rather annoying having to put this type of routing in the ProcessEvents() function.

During my reading last night, I read about the concept of registering & unregistering *listeners*.

This sounds like a great idea, but I'm at a complete loss as to exactly how this works or how I would implement it in VB.NET. I suppose the concept is this. If I create new *Monster* object, I would somehow register it as a listener for event types such as GunShoot, BombExplode, etc. During the processing of events by the Event Manager, if it comes across a BombExplode event, it would poll each registered listener if they can consume the event.

How could this be implemented efficiently in VB.NET?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the perfect scenario for the built in [WeakEvent Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) in .NET.

If you made your subscribers implement [IWeakEventListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iweakeventlistener.aspx) appropriately, and created the appropriate [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx) classes, you could have listeners that listened to the "event manager" events (which could be implemented in numerous ways), without having to worry about lifetime issues causing memory "leaks".